# how to edit default tinymce of wordpress that is default provided

Tags: php, wordpress, web, tinymce

I have just upgraded wordpress version 4.2.5 to wordpress 4.4. I have used another plugin for tinymce-advance 2.5.8 but it doesnot work for me. I want to add another button too in tinymce editor like align-left, align-center, align-right,bulets and numbering.

Can anybody tell me the idea to put those ribbon button in wordpress 4.4 and wordpress 4.2.5

Comment: Are you trying to add the buttons to the visual editor, or to the text editor?